# Delete Button - Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add a "Delete" button to my product-page, but I am constantly having troubles with this error:

### Error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event
>   validation is enabled using  in
>   configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. 
>   For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to
>   postback or callback events originate from the server control that
>   originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.]
>   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId,
>   String argument) +8730646
>   System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String uniqueID, String
>   eventArgument) +113
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +35
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +36    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +5563

### What I've tried:

Throughout my research I've learned that I can use `enableEventValidation="false"` and `validateRequest="false"` but due to security-reasons its not recommended.
I tried to set both to False, it fixed the problem (thought I don't have a DELETE Query inserted), but I don't feel comfortable with having some security-settings turned off, just to get rid of an error.

My repeater is located inside the Page_Load, and since I'm using a masterpage, the repeater is also in a form.

### Aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RepProductMenu" OnItemCommand="RepProducts_ItemCommand">
<ItemTemplate>
         [Lots of stuff]......

        <asp:Button ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" CommandArguement='<%# Eval("ID") %>' /

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

### Aspx.cs:

```
protected void RepProducts_ItemCommand(Object Sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        int ID = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        // Add Delete Query
        Response.Write("COMMAND");
    }
}
```

Any suggestions and idéas are appreciated.

Comment: Is the repeater inside a form?

Comment: How is your repeater bound? Is it in the page_load? Do you have "If !(Page.IsPostBack)" wrapped around it?

Comment: The repeater is locate inside my Masterpage, so yes it's inside a form.

Comment: The repeater is inside page_load and NOT in a if !(page.IsPostBack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found the issue and it is not working. I will provide my new code and hopefully, it can help you aswell :) Please keep in mind, I use a DataAccess in my codebehind so you should just enter your own code there, nonetheless, take a look:

**

## Old Code:

**

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RepProductMenu" OnItemCommand="RepProducts_ItemCommand">
<ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Button ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" Text="Slet" CommandName="DeleteProduct" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>



 protected void RepProducts_ItemCommand(Object Sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "DeleteProduct")
        {
            int ID = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            // Add Delete Query
            Response.Write("COMMAND");
        }
    }
```

First of all, it's not supposed to be a `RepeaterCommandEventArgs`, but `CommandEventArgs`

**

### New Code:

**

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RepProductMenu" >
<ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Button ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" Text="Slet" CommandName="DeleteProduct" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>

protected void OnItemCommand(Object Sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "DeleteProduct")
    {
        DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();

        int ID = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        dataAccess.AddParameter("@id", ID);
        dataAccess.Execute(@"DELETE FROM [Product] WHERE ID = @ID");
        //Response.Write("COMMAND");
    }
}
```

Comment: nice to see you found the problem :)

Answer (score 9):

Avoid using `Delete` as a `CommandName`, as I believe this is reserved.

Also you have a typo in your `Button` control. `CommandArguement` should be `CommandArgument`

---

If your repeater is being binded at `Page_Load` and not inside `if !(page.IsPostBack)` then it will be rebound when the `Delete` button is clicked. This may cause a problem as the repeater will be rebound before your `ItemCommand` is ran. Which would make it invalid.

Try changing your code so that `if !(page.IsPostBack)` is wrapped around the bind.

Comment: I just wrapped my binding(s) inside a if (!IsPostBack), it didn't get rid of the error.

Comment: If I just insert a normal button with no purpose, then it gives me the same error.. It's weird how every button generates the error.

Comment: Where you've put `[Lots of stuff]......`, can we see what is actually there? Is there any client scripting in textboxes at all? This is sometimes the cause of this sort of error.

Comment: Also, try removing all the other stuff, and see if you still get an error.

Comment: All I have in [Lots of stuff].. Is some tr/td's with codes like "<%# ((Product)Container.DataItem).CategoryName %>". But I tried to remove everything and just have the button, the error still appears.. And actually, the error ONLY appears in the Repeater.. If I put the button outside the repeater - the error doesnt appear.

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was that the repeater's data-binding in a Page_Load method needed to be put inside 'if (!IsPostBack)' block.

Instead of :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileLinksRepeater.DataSource = _DataSource;
    FileLinksRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

try this :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FileLinksRepeater.DataSource = _DataSource;
        FileLinksRepeater.DataBind();
    }   
}
```

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: amazingly it solved the problem for me in SharePoint too. and i change enableEventValidation back to "false" in webconfig